# Lots of abstract classes, am I missing a design pattern?

Tags: oop, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have two classes: `Transaction` and `TempTransaction` which extend from an abstract class, `AbstractTransaction`.

Because the construction of of these objects is complex (there are a lot or rules to implement) I have a builder classes for each type. I also have repositories for the two types of transaction and 'writers' that deal with persistence.

Because `Transaction` and `TempTransaction` both have slightly different behavior (e.g. `Transaction` is almost completely immutable) I need to enforce the types that are passed around. I have done this by having abstract classes that the Temp and non-Temp classes inherit from, and then implementing override methods that type hint for the concrete classes and then call the parent method in the abstract class.

This means I end up with lots of abstract classes, like so:-

- AbstractBuilder
- AbstractWriter
- AbstractRepository

And I'm sure there will be more as I add functionality to this module. I feel like I might be missing some design pattern to help with this polymorphism - when reading about the basics of OOP we are always told to look for alternatives to inheritance as a way to introduce polymorphism...

Comment: Consider using Interfaces as well as Abstract Classes - they meet different (and only partially overlapping) design criteria in OOP.  For a start: use an AbstractClass when you actually desire to share implementation, and an Interface when you only want to expose commonality of function.

Comment: Yes, I'm using interfaces where possible, but the examples here all share a good bit of functionality. I have an interface between the `TransactionWriter` and the DBAL of the framework I'm using, for instance. So it should be fairly straight forward to use this module in another framework (or with a different DBAL).